# Latest Composer version not pulling Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

The Latest version of Composer is not pulling Laravel, I thought it could be because of Composer added new secure_http feature for downloading from Packagist and Laravel Packagist are in HTTP. This is what I think, so I need solution. The previous version of Composer doing well.
The error showing on my terminal when I was trying to install Laravel installer, is:

> Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error Retrying with degraded mode, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode for more info Your configuration does not allow connection to http://packagist.org. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details. http://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content. [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Your configuration does not allow connection to http://packagist.org. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had the same problem. Found the solution here:[Reddit Discussion of the issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/47jc25/todays_composer_release_04a1085d_breaks_https/)

Basically, you have two options:

- Revert to previous version, by running

  `self-update --rollback`
- Or, downgrade composer by running

  `composer config -g secure-http false`

Comment: Yes you are right. I got that first solution and working that way, actually I downloaded the previous version of Composer and make change the mod to 755 and paste in ``/usr/local/bin/`` directory. But the second solution you gave I tried to edit in composer.phar file but somehow I was getting error. Okay, thanks for your help. I will try the second one.

Comment: When I try to revert to previous version it spits out this error: [InvalidArgumentException]
  Command "self-update" is not defined.

Answer (score 12):

at last this one saved me ,

```
sudo composer self-update

sudo composer clear-cache

sudo composer config -g secure-http false

sudo composer update --no-scripts
```

finally done !

Answer (score 2):

When running (downgrade composer by running)

```
composer config -g secure-http false
```

i still got an exeption

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Composer\Package\RootPackage::getConfig() ...
```

I got a success finaly using additional --no-plugins

```
composer config -g secure-http false --no-plugins
composer self-update --no-plugins
```

Hope this helps anyone :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to enable openssl using:

`composer config -g -- disable-tls false`

And then you also need to active it in php.in

Open php.ini and search for `php_openssl` and you end up like this `extension=php_openssl.dll`

The `php_openssl.dll` file is in ext directory of your php so if you changed php directory and have an error like

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'C:\php\ext\php_openssl.dll' - The specified module could not be found. 
in Unknown on line 0
```

You need to set `extension=php_openssl.dll` to `extension="your php direcroty"\ext\php_openssl.dll`