# How to enable composer SSL/TLS protection in xampp server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

Hello I am fresher in Laravel. I installed the xampp server into the **E:\xampp>**

directory and I installed the composer into the **C:>** directory.I downloaded

the laravel project from the laravel site.then for some dependency I have to

install the composer into my project  directory but when I install

composer using the following command

**composer install**

I find the error like

```
You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
Loading composer repositories with package information


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  Your configuration does not allow connections to http://packagist.org/packa
  ges.json. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for deta
  ils.


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-c
ustom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest
] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
 [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

How to resolve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249620/the-openssl-extension-is-required-for-ssl-tls-protection)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003429/latest-composer-version-not-pulling-laravel

Comment: @Stony when i am using   composer config -g -- disable-tls true it is not working for me

Answer (score -3):

composer config -g -- disable-tls true

maby can help you

(i've occured that problem, openserver solved it
for example, I used Uwamp before)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The person asking the question already said this did not work for him or her. Is there a special reason you still recommend this? Would it have a chance of succeeding depending on some environment settings? Please [edit] your question and clarify. Thanks!

Comment: He's talking about enabling the tls and ssl not the other way around please raed the problem first before giving a solution