# How to fix "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json does not contain valid Json"?

Tags: composer-php, vagrant, symfony4

I've an issue with composer running on a vagrantbox (Centos 7), which started to just suddenly happen.

I've already tried manually running the command/solution mentioned on the link below but to no avail.

(To clarify, ***i'm using vagrant not docker***, but it was the closest question i found to my situation. Most of the information i found are related to composer.json not being valid, but here is packagist.org/packages.json which, is currently valid)

[Composer not working in docker container: "https://packagist.org/packages.json" does not contain valid JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50103847/composer-not-working-in-docker-container-https-packagist-org-packages-json)

***Here are the details of the issue.***

While running `composer update` on terminal i get:

```
 composer update


  [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
  "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" does not contain valid JSON
  Parse error on line 1:

  ^
  Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

And when running `composer install` also on terminal every package returns this:

```
Failed to download psr/cache from dist: "https://api.github.com/repos/php-fig/cache/zipball/d11b50ad223250cf17b86e38383413f5a6764bf8" 
appears broken, and returned an empty 200 response
    Now trying to download from source
```

When running `composer config --global repo.packagist composer packagist.org`
the results are now

```
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  Your configuration does not allow connections to http://repo.packagist.org/packages.json. See https://getcomposer.o
  rg/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
```

Any ideas why this started to happen, how can i fix it?

Comment: this is a little bit confugins .. are you using docker or vagrant ? the command above which is "composer update"  .. did you run it form terminal or is it inside dockerfile ? .. please add more details

Comment: Updated and edited, hopefully its more clear now. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: your vm has access to public ? can you ping google.com ?

Comment: Yes I can ping. If i actually perform the composer install, after the message i showed on the issue description it continues to download and install the packages, but takes a lot more time than with regular/normal behavior and shows that message for every single package. Composer update is a no go still after installing completes

Comment: did you try solution there  which is  composer config --global repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org

Comment: Updated above with result of running that command

Comment: try to configure php.ini  - -extension=php_openssl.dll   ... and have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818464/configuration-does-not-allow-connection-to-http-packagist-org-packages-json/38818895

Comment: Tried to configure php.ini on centos as that's where my php and composer run but no changes. But i've found that i'm able to run composer update while disabling https. It's a security risk but i'll mention it nevertheless.
As it's mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36175869/11335693

Answer (score 6, accepted):

same problem here, since php updated to 7.2.17.
On a centos 7 with php 7.2.16 composer run just fine...
Rollback to 7.2.16 is for now the only solution found...

Edit : 
Seems to be a symfony flex issue : https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/484

Comment: Thanks for the headsup! I'm on php 7.3 and as mentioned on that issue, it happened on that version too. I'm marking this question as resolved with your comment since it is now fixed in relation to the github issue you mention and its corresponding commit.


**Just reinstall your packages!**  

(Note: Might have to delete vendor folder and composer.lock for a fresh install)

Comment: This answer inspired me. I got `repo.packagist.org:443; Connection refused` and `repo.packagist.org:80; Connection refused` errors, even `2001:41d0:801:1000::27d: Network is unreachable` errors. Then I read your answer, found out we have `PHP 7.1.29`. I ran the `composer diagnose` via `PHP 7.2.18` and `5.6.40`, and it worked! This mystical issue finally solved!

Answer (score 14):

Could also be IPv6 related, if your provider/system is configured for IPv6 but has no valid IPv6 route out to the internet.

This happened to me, and doing
`sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1` (as root), then trying composer again fixed the issue.

To permanently apply it, add the rule to /etc/sysctl.conf (or wherever your OS preferred is)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After days of searching, I found a solution. It seems a PHP problem. Try to comment a line of curl extension on php.ini. I am using php version 5.6.

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Type ; before the extension name, at least it will be like this:

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue try to install symfony twig bundle. I ran :

```
set http_proxy=
set https_proxy=
composer require symfony/twig-bundle
```

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I ran a `composer global require laravel/installer` simply upgrading laravel/installer according to Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation#the-laravel-installer and the error was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just had to install the *php-curl* package, as suggested by `composer diagnose`.

Answer (score -1):

Simply Just check out your internet and it well be ok

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33004233)

Answer (score -2):

```
My solution: connect to a vpn before running the command!
```

For me basically the problem was because my IP was from Iran. Connected to a vpn and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score -4):

it will works when we run this command in console

```
composer config disable-tls true
```

Comment: This is disabling a security feature, can't be considered a real solution to the original problem

Answer (score -7):

I bypassed the problem by redirecting the output to `/dev/null`.

```
composer require symfony/orm-pack > /dev/null
```

Comment: That doesn't actually fix the problem, it just hides it.